# IP address is showing in form action with CodeIgniter http://::1/codeigniter/ in html sourcecode

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I have the CI script installed on Xampp. Currently I am working on forms and when I click on submit on html, it does nothing.

I tried

```
echo form_open('verifylogin');
echo form_open();
```

It show on sourcecode as

```
<form action="http://::1/codeigniter/verifylogin">
<form action="http://::1/codeigniter/">
```

respectively.

I don't understand what this `"http://::1/"` is and how to get rid of it?

Comment: if I rmb right, its a ipv6 loopback on ipv4 ?? need someone to clarify

Comment: Edit your question, give details, show the activation of the form, the result, and the expected result.... finally `::1` is the IPv6 equivalent of `localhost` or IPv4 `127.0.0.1`

Comment: IPv6 localhost address look like what you have. IPv4 address tend to look like this:`http://127.0.0.1`.

My advice is too look into your XAMPP/apache/CI environment and find the equivalent IPv4 hostnames.

Comment: Have you set (and how) `$config['base_url']` in `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If ip address is displayed in **form action** or **url**

- `http://::1/yourproject/`
- `http://127.0.0.1/yourproject/`

Chances are you have left the base url blank

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| WARNING: You MUST set this value!
|
| If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
| your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
| to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
| The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
| development and MUST NOT be used in production!
|
| If you need to allow multiple domains, remember that this file is still
| a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
|
*/

$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Now days in latest versions of codeIgniter it is not recommend that you leave your base_url blank.

- `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`
- `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

And is always good to end url with `/`

You may need to create routes for your form here

```
application > config > routes.php
```

**CodeIgniter 3:** [Routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

**CodeIgniter 2:** [Routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html)

---

**Update:**

> With CodeIgniter 3 + versions:

When you create a file remember you will have to have **first letter ONLY** upper case on `file names` and `classes`.

What will happen sometimes is that it all may well work in a localhost environment with lower case but when you go to a live server **some times** will throw errors or not submit forms correct etc.

Example: From [Controllers](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world) This also applies to [Models](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model)

## This is valid

**File name:** Verifylogin.php

```
<?php

class Verifylogin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

    }

}
```

---

## This is valid

**File name:** Verify_login.php

```
<?php

class Verify_login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

    }

}
```

---

## This is **not** valid

**File name:** verifylogin.php

```
class verifylogin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

    }

}
```

---

## This is **not** valid

**File name:** Verify_Login.php

```
class Verify_Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

    }

}
```

Codeigniter [Doc's](http://www.codeigniter.com/docs)

Comment: @CodeIgniter I would also recommend using the codeigniter form helper when use form.

Answer (score 8):

Go to application/config/config.php set base_url

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/example/';`

And refresh your application

Then `::1` error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to System/core/Config.php**

**Set config in line 84**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config =& get_config();

    // Set the base_url automatically if none was provided
    if (empty($this->config['base_url']))
    {
        // The regular expression is only a basic validation for a valid "Host" header.
        // It's not exhaustive, only checks for valid characters.
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && preg_match('/^((\[[0-9a-f:]+\])|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})|[a-z0-9\-\.]+)(:\d+)?$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
        {
            $base_url = (is_https() ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
                .substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])));
        }
        else
        {
            $base_url = 'http://localhost/';
        }

        $this->set_item('base_url', $base_url);
    }


    log_message('info', 'Config Class Initialized');
}
```

Comment: I would not mess around with files that are in the system core folder.

Comment: i was about to post this solution. This is the actual solution for the problem. sometimes you need to take risk.

Answer (score 0):

Remove / from url

Previous :

```
<li><a href="/<?=site_url('contacts/create')?>">New Contact</a></li>
```

After :

```
<li><a href="<?=site_url('contacts/create')?>">New Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing the "/" in the redirect

Before:

`header("Location: /index.php?error=TRUE")`

After:

`header("Location: index.php?error=TRUE")`