# why i'm having this [::1] in my URL using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

need your experties here sir/maam

im just wondering why im having this in my url [::1] every time i clicked my button. please help here..

> //[::1]/myfirstwebsite/index.php/auth/login

[image]

even when i use inspect elemet

[image]

Comment: because you're using ipv6

Comment: [::1] refers to localhost in IPv6 format.

Comment: So what should i do.. newbie here sir. Sorry

Comment: This will explain why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025305/ip-address-is-showing-in-form-action-with-codeigniter-http-1-codeigniter-in/34031347#34031347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using IPv6 and most-likely don't have `$config['base_url']` set in your config.php file.

[Refer to this documentation for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025305/ip-address-is-showing-in-form-action-with-codeigniter-http-1-codeigniter-in/34031347#34031347)

Comment: I had the same link in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

When your url in form action shows

- `http://::1/project_name/`

Chances are you have left the base url blank

$config['base_url'] = '';

In latest versions of codeIgniter it is not recommend that you leave your base_url blank.

- `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name/';`