# codeigniter page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have created project in Codeigniter. This project is working in localhost Wamp but i have uploaded online server is not working

in localhost working url

```
http://localhost/newjob/index.php/home
```

but after upload on server this url not working

```
http://example.com/index.php/home
```

and

```
http://example.com/
```

Controller

```
<?php class Home extends Controller {

      public function index() {

          echo "home page";

      }    } ?>
```

Config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

Comment: Your `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: No need for `?>` at end of controller or models in codeIgniter Make sure all file names has first letter upper case Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025305/ip-address-is-showing-in-form-action-with-codeigniter-http-1-codeigniter-in/34031347#34031347

Comment: `class Home extends Controller` is wrong. Use `class Home extends CI_Controller`.

Comment: Which CodeIgniter version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your home controler name start with H("Home.php"), rename to home.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think the http://example.com/index.php is enough because it's a file and can't have a folder in a file