# redirect wrong pass in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, redirect, http-status-code-404

I wrote an application using Codeigniter and I have uploaded it in my host. My application worked perfectly until 2 days ago. Now when I want access to my application the Url redirects to an IP and a 404 (Not Found) page is shown.

I am sure that did not changed any code in my program. Ty url I am trying to access access:
 http://hoomskin.com/ticket/index.php/Answerc
[image: 404-picture]
please help me

Comment: Have you left the base url blank in config.php? If so you need to set it. See question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025305/ip-address-is-showing-in-form-action-with-codeigniter-http-1-codeigniter-in/34031347#34031347

Comment: wolfgang1983 yes worked,thanks my problem solved

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thank you ;)