# Codeigniter object not found error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

**I have made a login system, but when i click on "login" i got this error message:
"error 404 object not found".**

I do not know whatto do now :S.

Here is my code:

My login file (the main file with the buttons)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>WELCOME! &raquo; Jaranguda.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <hr>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url('Login/user')?>" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cari">USERNAME</label>
                <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cari">PASSWORD</label>
                <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" class="form-control">

            </div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">

        </form>
            </div>



    </body>
```

The controller file:

```
<?php

    class Login extends CI_Controller{

     public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model("Login_model");

    }

    public function index(){

        $this->load->view("login");

    }

    public function user(){

        $data['login']=$this->Login_model->login();
        $this->load->view('user', $data);

    }



    }

?>
```

The model file:

```
<?php

class Login_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){

     $this->load->database();

    }

    public function login(){

        $usuario=$this->input->POST('usuario', TRUE);
        $contrasena=md5($this->input->POST('contrasena', TRUE));
        $data=$this->db->query("SELECT * from usuarios where usuario=$usuario and contrasena=$contrasena LIMIT 1");
        return $data=row();

      }

}

?>
```

The user file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="">

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>BIENVENIDO! &raquo; Jaranguda.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>

    </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <hr>

<?php
if(count($login)>0)
{
    if($login->tipo=='0')
        echo "<p>YOU LOGGED AS: <b>".$login->tipo."</p>"

}

    elseif($login->tipo =='1'){

        echo "<p>usuario <b>".$login->usuario."</b> LOGGED AS: <b>".$login->tipo."</p>"

    }

    else{

        echo "<p>usuario <b>".$login->usuario."</b> SOMETHING WENT WRONG WHILE LOGGING</p>"

    }

?>

<?php


}
else
{

    echo "<p>USERNAME/PASSWORD INVALID.</p>"

}


?>

    </div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope you can help me :S

Comment: Just a tip don't use md5 for passwords very unsecure when create password use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and to verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Gonna check this out :)

Comment: This is a old tutorial but good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmKm1gCgUoM&list=PL161C7E0E6A01B1E0 there are a lot of  tutorial 
 on you tube about login in

Comment: Your also missing `parent::__construct();` here `public function __construct(){` in model and best to auto load the database as said many times. `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');` that way you dont have to load it in each fille

Comment: This may come in handy also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025305/ip-address-is-showing-in-form-action-with-codeigniter-http-1-codeigniter-in/34031347#34031347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login method **should** in `Login_model` return :

```
 return $data->row();
```

**not** :

```
return $data = row();
```

## Edit

You need to pass the user info to your mode:

this two line should be in your controller:

```
  public function user(){
        $usuario=$this->input->post('usuario', TRUE);
        $contrasena=md5($this->input->post('contrasena', TRUE));
        $data['login']=$this->Login_model->login($usuario, $contrasena);
        $this->load->view('user', $data);    
    }
```

and your **model** :

```
 public function login($usuario, $contrasena) {
   $this->db->where('usuario',$usuario);
   $this->db->where('contrasena',$contrasena);
   $query = $this->db->get("your_table_name");
   return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139697/discussion-on-answer-by-amr-aly-codeigniter-object-not-found-error).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The URL shown in the image above is typical of what happens if a `$config['base_url']` is not set in `application/config/config.php`.

You MUST set a value for that config item. It must contain the protocol `http` or `https`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

On an unnamed virtual server it would probably be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

or maybe

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost';
```

I cannot remember. Also, the above might need a trailing '/' e.g. `localhost/`

Comment: show me the url displayed when the form is showing.

Comment: See revised answer

Comment: are you still seeing the `[::1]` in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: No, it just disappeared

Comment: thati s really strange